# Receiving several deadlocks with simple queries when ran concurrently from different nodes

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, deadlock

We have a web application with three nodes that sit behind a load balancer that handles traffic in a round robin fashion (no sticky sessions). When we receive several requests coming in at the same time we will start to see several deadlocks occurring on one of our queries that obtains a session id. We have a table called `uniqueids` that we populate with around 250,000 rows that contains sequential ids specific to our application. We use the stored procedure `getnextsessionid` to select the next unused id and then update the used column in that row to show it has been used. Is there a different locking method we can use to ensure no two people receive the same id and prevent deadlocks?

```
ALTER    PROCEDURE [dbo].[getnextsessionID] 

    (
    @id varchar(15) OUT
    )

AS

    SET NOCOUNT ON
    SET LOCK_TIMEOUT 8000

    BEGIN TRAN
        SELECT TOP 1 @id = RTRIM(LTRIM(sessionID))
        FROM uniqueids WITH (HOLDLOCK,ROWLOCK,INDEX = session_used)
        WHERE used = 0

        UPDATE uniqueids
        SET used = 1,dt = GetDate()
        WHERE sessionID = @id

    COMMIT TRAN

--uniqueids table

    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[uniqueids](
        [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [sessionID] [varchar](15) NOT NULL,
        [used] [bit] NOT NULL,
        [dt] [smalldatetime] NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK_uniqueids_id] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [ID] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 85) ON [PRIMARY],
     CONSTRAINT [U_sessionID] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
    (
        [sessionID] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 85) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY]


    CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [session_used] ON [dbo].[uniqueids]
    (
        [used] ASC,
        [sessionID] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 85) ON [PRIMARY]
    GO

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[uniqueids] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_uniqueids_used1]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [used]
```

Comment: For one thing, read operations can occur on multiple nodes but write operations only occur on the primary. So you might consider moving the traffic to your primary since this is a write. What you could do is allow for dirty reads (again, primary) to avoid using the same id, or my preference is use a staging table which then exports them in order

Comment: I guess the question is does the info need to be ready for processing immediately and what is the window that can be extended between writing and processing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use an `UPDATE` with an `OUTPUT` instead of two completely separate statements.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.getnextsessionID
  @id varchar(15) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  DECLARE @t TABLE(id varchar(15));

  ;WITH NextID AS 
  (
    SELECT TOP (1) sessionID,used
      FROM dbo.uniqueids 
      WHERE used = 0
      ORDER BY ID
  )
  UPDATE NextID SET used = 1 
    OUTPUT deleted.sessionID INTO @t;

  SELECT @id = RTRIM(LTRIM(id)) FROM @t;
END
GO
```

Also if the table is large (and as the set where `used = 1` grows), I might suggest a filtered index instead, simply because it's much cheaper to maintain:

```
CREATE INDEX session_used 
  ON dbo.uniqueids(ID, sessionID, used) 
  WHERE used = 0
  WITH (DROP_EXISTING = ON);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to rewrite your SP like below:

```
ALTER    PROCEDURE [dbo].[getnextsessionID] 

    (
    @id varchar(15) OUT
    )

AS

    SET NOCOUNT ON
    SET LOCK_TIMEOUT 8000

    DECLARE @Out TABLE (
        Id  varchar(15)
    )

    WITH cte AS
    (
        SELECT TOP (1) Id
        FROM uniqueids
        WHERE used = 0
        ORDER BY [sessionID]
    )
    UPDATE u
    SET used = 1, dt = GetDate()
    OUTPUT inserted.sessionID INTO @Out(Id)
    FROM uniqueids u
        JOIN cte ON cte.Id = u.Id

    SET @id = (SELECT TOP (1) Id FROM @Out)
```

The idea is to use one query to update your table and to get @Id. This case a concurrent session can't touch the same row because of UPDLOCK that's why you won't come across deadlocks.